# Why adding a object to an attribute of the another object of the same class have the side effect of adding it to both objects in python

Tags: python, oop

It's easier to explain my issue with an example so here it goes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class Node:

    _name: str = None
    _parents = []

    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self._name = name

    def add_parent(self, node):
        self._parents.append(node)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    foo = Node("foo")
    bar = Node("bar")

    foo.add_parent(bar)

    print("= foo")
    print(foo._parents)
    print(list(map(lambda n: n._name, foo._parents)))

    print("= bar")
    print(bar._parents)
    print(list(map(lambda n: n._name, bar._parents)))
```

and this is the result:

```
= foo
[<__main__.Node object at 0x7fdd66d9ac90>]
['bar']
= bar
[<__main__.Node object at 0x7fdd66d9ac90>]
['bar']
```

why is the `bar` object added to itself too?

I would expect it to be added only to foo._parents so to me this is a side effect maybe even a bug in Python.

Answer (score 1):

`_parents` is defined as a class variable. As such, it is shared among all instances of this class.

Instance variables need to be defined on an instance, for example in `__init__` method.

Initially `_name` is defined as a class variable as well, but you are immediately shadowing it with `self._name` variable created in an instace. You are not reassigning `self._parents`, so all instances refer to the same class variable.

```
class Node:

    _name: str = "CLASS"
    _parents = []

    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self._name = name

    def add_parent(self, node):
        self._parents.append(node)

foo = Node("foo")
bar = Node("bar")

foo.add_parent(bar)

print(f"{foo._name = }")
print(f"{foo.__class__._name = }")

print(f"{id(foo._name) = }")
print(f"{id(bar._name) = }")

print(f"{id(foo._parents) = }")
print(f"{id(bar._parents) = }")
```

Notice how ids of `_name` are different, but `_parents` have the same id, meaning it's the same object.

Comment: shortly: create _parents in the init() method and it will work as ou expect

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to explain why it's working the way it does.

Comment: class variable is like a static variable in other languages (C++, Java). All class instances share the same variable. So you add items to the same list

Answer (score 1):

foo and bar are class attributes and are shared between class *instances*
You should define them in the `__init__` method to make them instance attributes

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self._name = name
        self._parents = []

    def add_parent(self, node):
        self._parents.append(node)
```

Also, notice you're using a list which can be updated by different objects